# Is 2 always a generator of the unit group Z_{3^m} for any nonzero positive integer m?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, cyclic-groups

Is $2$ always a generator of the unit group of $Z_{3^m}$ for any nonzero positive integer m?

I know that $|\langle 2\rangle | > m \;Log_2(3)$, and by Lagrange $|\langle 2\rangle|\>\lVert\>  2\times3^{m-1}$.

Comment: You are essentially asking if $2$ is a primitive root modulo $3^m$. It is possible to prove that if $k$ is a primitive root modulo $p^r$ with $p$ and prime and $r\gt 1$, then $k$ is also a primitive root modulo $p^{r+1}$. So you just need to check if it is a primitive root modulo $3^2$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Modulo $3^2$? How? (What directly follows from your previous statement is that you need to check if it's a primitive root module $3^{m + 1}$).

Comment: @M.Vinay: No: if it is a primitive root modulo $p^2$, then it is a primitive root modulo $p^3$; and hence modulo $p^4$, and hence modulo $p^5$; and hence modulo $p^6$; etc. What makes you think you need to check that it is a primitive root modulo $p^{m+1}$?

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Of I see now. I was taking the immediate implication of the statement "$k$ a primitive root modulo $p^r$ ($r > 1$) $\implies$ $k$ a primitive root modulo $p^{r + 1}$", instead of applying it "backwards" [which is possible and necessary because we have to prove it for all $r$ ($m$) here].

Comment: @M.Vinay: I do not understand your comment. The implication goes precisely in the direction we want: if you have it for $r$, then you have it for $r+1$ (provided that $r\gt 1$; primitive roots modulo $p$ need not be primitive roots modulo $p^2$).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Sorry, I'm having a slow day. I started with the idea that we need to prove this for an arbitrary $m$ (which is correct), but then for some reason, instead of thinking of what could *imply* this, started thinking about what this would *imply*. Everything's clear now.